Fitting curve using real Gauss distribution in Python
I have a set of points, their scattered image resemblances to a Gaussian  normal distribution. Searching the internet there are many Python sample how to fit a curve to the points. They based on:
def Gauss1(X, C, mu, sigma):
    return C * np.exp(-(X-mu) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

and
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

This produce a very well fit curve. The problem is that Gauss1 is not the Gaussian normal distribution, it should be:
def Gauss2(X, mu, sigma):
    return (1 / (sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))) * np.exp(-(X-mu) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

Using Gauss2 produces the next message and there is no popt:
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated

Is any way to generate the fitting curve using the real Gaussian distribution?
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(Gauss2, x, y)

OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated

I think the points are not needed, but I can publish 25 lines.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Follow the convention
import numpy as np              # Library for working with arrays
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

######################################## G L O B A L S
# X the ratings after grouping by 23 the chess players from FIDE 2024 Oct Standard
# Y is the average of players in the averaged ratings
XY = (
    (1411, 231), (1434, 271), (1457, 281), (1480, 287), 
    (1503, 292), (1526, 298), (1549, 293), (1572, 299), 
    (1595, 300), (1618, 303), (1641, 304), (1664, 308), 
    (1687, 301), (1710, 311), (1733, 304), (1756, 291), 
    (1779, 286), (1802, 283), (1825, 279), (1848, 268), 
    (1871, 260), (1894, 243), (1917, 229), (1940, 221), 
    (1963, 203), (1986, 169), (2009, 134), (2032, 112), 
    (2055, 102), (2078,  94), (2101,  81), (2124,  76), 
    (2147,  70), (2170,  61), (2193,  54), (2216,  45), 
    (2239,  42), (2262,  35), (2285,  31), (2308,  27), 
    (2331,  26), (2354,  22), (2377,  20), (2400,  18), 
    (2423,  15), (2446,  10), (2469,  10), (2492,   7), 
    (2515,   6), (2538,   5), (2561,   4), (2584,   3), 
    (2607,   3), (2630,   2), (2653,   2), (2676,   2), 
    (2699,   1), (2722,   2), (2745,   1), (2768,   1), 
    (2791,   1), (2837,   1))

class c:  # Constants
    X_LABEL_STEP = 50
    Y_LABEL_STEP = 10
    A4 = (11.69, 8.27)  # W x H in inches

###################################### F U N C T I O N S

def Graph_Gauss():
    global c, XY

    X = [] ; Y = []
    for e in XY:
        X += [e[0]]
        Y += [e[1]]

    # Set up the limits for X, ratings
    minX = min(X) ; maxX = max(X)
    # Set up the limits for Y, number of players with that rating
    minY = min(Y) ; maxY = max(Y)
        
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(c.A4)
    fig.suptitle("Rating Distribution", fontsize=18, y=0.935)

    x1  = []  # Make the x axle
    xlb = []  # Make the labels for x
    stp = c.X_LABEL_STEP
    for k in range(stp*(minX//stp), stp*(maxX//stp + 2), stp):
        x1 += [k]
        xlb.append(f"{k}")
    ax.set_xticks(ticks=x1, labels=xlb, rotation=270)
    ax.set_xlabel("Rating", fontsize=15, labelpad=7)

    stp = c.Y_LABEL_STEP
    yticks = np.arange(stp*(minY//stp), stp*(maxY//stp + 2), stp)
    ax.set_ylabel("Number of Players", fontsize=15, rotation=270, labelpad=18)
    ax.set_yticks(ticks=yticks)
    ax.grid(which="major", axis="both")

    ax.scatter(X, Y, color="#000FFF", marker='o', s=14)

    # plt.show()

    # Fit a normal distribution, aka Gaussian fitting curve
    # https://www.wasyresearch.com/tutorial-python-for-fitting-gaussian-distribution-on-data/
    # mu = mean = sum(x) / len(x) ; In our case sum(x * y) / sum(y)
    # sigma = standard deviation = sqrt((sum((x - mean)**2) / len(x))
    #
    # https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/normal-distribution/
    # 1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)) * e**(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
    # Calculating the Gaussian PDF values given Gaussian parameters and random variable X
    def Gauss1(X, C, mu, sigma):
        return C * np.exp(-(X-mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
    def Gauss2(X, mu, sigma):
        return (1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))) * np.exp(-(X-mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))

    x = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(Y)
    mu    = sum(x * y) / sum(y)                  
    sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y*(x - mu)**2)/sum(y))

    print(f"{1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))=:.2f} {mu=:.2f} {sigma=:.2f}")

    popt1, pcov1 = curve_fit(Gauss1, x, y, p0=[max(y), mu, sigma], maxfev=5000)
    popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(Gauss2, x, y)  # This generates:
    # OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated

    yg1 = Gauss1(x, *popt1)
    yg2 = Gauss2(x, *popt2)
    
    ax.plot(x, yg1, color="#FF0F00", linewidth=3,
            label=f"Normal: mu={popt1[1]:.2f}, sigma={popt1[2]:.2f}")
    plt.legend(fontsize=12)

    breakpoint()  # ???? DEBUG

    plt.show()
    pass  # To set a breakpoint

#######################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # breakpoint()  # ???? DEBUG, to set other breakpoints
    Graph_Gauss()

Added on Oct. 28, 2024
Hi Aldehyde and Lastchance,
Thank you very much for your answers, it is getting clearer. Now I have two questions:
•   What is exactly the Gaussian distribution function, where is the sigma; I couldn’t figure out from the many internet search hits.
•   For using the Gauss2() you normalized the y values by 230,000 and this produced a well-fitting curve. I tried a few other numbers, 240,000 even gives a better fit. Where this or a similar number comes from. I tried np.sum(y)=8,241 and the area below the dots np.sum((x[1:]-x[:-1]) * ((y[1:]+y[:-1])/2)) = 186,898, they gave a bad fit.
So what is the right method, how can 240,000 or something similar number be deducted from the given 62 points. If you can recommend a text or some other book, where I can find the answer, it is also fine.
Thanks, again,
Vilmos

The curve that you wish to fit is a probability density function. Its integral is 1. However, the y values that you are trying to fit are not probabilities. Their integral is nowhere near 1.

You have two major errors.

The data that you provide are BINNED FREQUENCIES, not PROBABILITY DENSITIES. However, the function Gauss2 that you are trying to fit is a probability density function (whose integral is 1).

You haven't provided all the data, so it's quite difficult to convert from a binned frequency to a probability density because you don't know the total number of people! (I've estimated it below.)


The connection between a binned frequency and a pdf is
binned frequency = number x pdf x dx

where number is the total number of people and dx is the bin width. Thus, you can fit your Gauss2 function to Y/(number*dx) rather than Y itself. When you come to plot it then you have to reverse that to get the frequencies.
I have had to estimate number=10000 (by assuming that it's about "twice the number after the maximum") because you didn't provide all the data; you can correct this in the code below from your full database.
Change your lines
popt1, pcov1 = curve_fit(Gauss1, x, y, p0=[max(y), mu, sigma], maxfev=5000)
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(Gauss2, x, y)
yg1 = Gauss1(x, *popt1)
yg2 = Gauss2(x, *popt2)
ax.plot(x, yg1, color="#FF0F00", linewidth=3,
        label=f"Normal: mu={popt1[1]:.2f}, sigma={popt1[2]:.2f}")

to the following (correcting number from the entire dataset):
popt1, pcov1 = curve_fit(Gauss1, x, y, p0=[max(y), mu, sigma], maxfev=5000)
yg1 = Gauss1(x, *popt1)

number = 10000   # this has been estimated: you didn't provide all of the data
dx     = 23      # bin width
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(Gauss2, x, y/(number*dx), p0=[mu, sigma] )
yg2 = Gauss2(x, *popt2) * number * dx

ax.plot(x, yg1, color="#FF0000", linewidth=3,
        label=f"Normal: mu={popt1[1]:.2f}, sigma={popt1[2]:.2f}")
ax.plot(x, yg2, color="#00FF00", linewidth=3,
        label=f"Normal: mu={popt2[0]:.2f}, sigma={popt2[1]:.2f}")



I would like to emphazise that you also gave an initial guess to curve_fit, which is quite essential in many cases too. The aforementionned error OptimizeWarning is very often due to curve_fit failling to fit, and when giving it an initial guess it very often helps. This is done by passing p0=[max(y), mu, sigma] as an argument to curve_fit. maxfev can also be set to higher value than default.

Yes, agreed - a good initial guess at the parameters is often essential (though I'm surprised that it worked here because about 30-40% of the data is missing, so the mean will be estimated high). The main problem in this instance, though, is one of scale: a cumulative frequency of 10000 or so (the number of players) is a long way away from a pdf integrating to 1.

Yes, having a function that has the same nature as the data is the first thing to consider.

Can somebody answer to my question, what I appended to the original on Oct. 28?

Not sure which of several questions you put in that paragraph you want an answer for. To give a “best” fit we would need all the data. sigma - which is the standard deviation of the Gaussian - is in popt2[1], since it is the second parameter being fitted.
